# How i can use variable from a select to call a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

My problem it's this code.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS agregar_abono$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  agregar_abono(IN pid_cliente BIGINT, IN pfecha_abono DATE, IN pmonto_abono FLOAT)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @idabono BIGINT;

    -- OTHER CODE ...

    SELECT id_abono AS idabono FROM abono WHERE fk_cliente = pid_cliente ORDER BY id_abono DESC LIMIT 1;

    SELECT CONCAT('>', idabono);


    CALL cobrar_abono(pid_cliente, vid_abono);

END $$
```

The procedure of the two SELECT return:

```
idabono = 52                  --> good! (in the first select)
CONCAT('>', idabono) = null   ---> what??
```

I don't know because don't stored the result in this variable to use in a stored procedure. I use a `AS` to store the variable.

The header of stored procedure to call is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cobrar_abono(IN pid_cliente BIGINT, IN pid_abono BIGINT)
```

Comment: Please explain how a value of your `vid_abono` variable should look like?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `CONCAT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
...
DECLARE idabono BIGINT;
-- OTHER CODE ...
SET idabono = (SELECT id_abono
                 FROM abono 
                WHERE fk_cliente = pid_cliente 
                ORDER BY id_abono DESC 
                LIMIT 1);
```

The `SELECT` statement itself probably can be replaced with

```sql
SET idabono = (SELECT MAX(id_abono)
                 FROM abono 
                WHERE fk_cliente = pid_cliente);
```

Comment: @felipedz Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Thanks @peterm... the code worked for me!, could you tell me what is the difference between `AS` and assign with `SET`. When you use each?

Comment: @felipedz `AS` doesn't assign it simply assigns a name to the column in the resultset. To assign a value to a variable you either use `SET` or `SELECT INTO`. Read [Variables in Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-variables.html) for clarification.